# Avoid reloading entire streamlit app on user input change

Tags: python, data-visualization, reload, latency, streamlit

I have been trying to build multiple plots in a streamlit app which intakes multiple user inputs for each plot (like: set threshold for graph X, choose variables for graph Y etc ) using either streamlit.radio . Though the app works fine, it reloads from very beginning every time any of the input is changed. As it is bulky, I wish to reload only those graphs for which the input has been changed. How can this be done? The dummy code can be considered as follows

```
x = st.radio('',(1,2,3))
plt.bar(a,b,width=x)

y = st.radio('',('left','right'))
plt.bar(a,b,align=y)
```

Now the problem is even if I just change 'y', the app also reloads the first graph which I wish to avoid.

Comment: To improve performance use a form widget. Allow the user to change variables when done let them press a button and then draw the plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `st.form()`

See the ink: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32106408)